# Applying custom light theme to android timePicker

Tags: android, themes

I want to apply custom light theme to android TimePicker. Currently I am having this code:

Theme Description:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

TimePicker description:

```
<TimePicker
         style="@style/MyTheme"
         android:id="@+id/timePicker1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
         android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
```

But text color of my TimePicker is still black, which looks really bad on dark background. So what should I do to change it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this!
Change the line style="@style/MyTheme" to android:theme="@style/MyTheme"